# is there a better way to sort values by minor column level labels in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, filter

Here is an example df:

```py
df3 = pd.DataFrame(
    data={"data_provider": ["prov_1", "prov_1", "prov_2", "prov_2", "prov_3", "prov_3"],
          "indicator": ["ind_a", "ind_a", "ind_a", "ind_b", "ind_b", "ind_b"],
          "unit": ["EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR"],
          "year": ["2017", "2018","2019", "2017","2018","2019"],
          "country1": [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6],
          "country2": [4, 5, 6, 40, 50, 60]}
)

df = pd.pivot_table(data=df3,
                     index=['data_provider', 'indicator'],
                     columns=['year', 'country1'],
                     fill_value=30)
```

Its structure looks like this way:

```py
                        country2                      
year                        2017     2018     2019    
country1                       1   2    2   4    3   6
data_provider indicator                               
prov_1        ind_a            4  30    5  30   30  30
prov_2        ind_a           30  30   30  30    6  30
              ind_b           30  40   30  30   30  30
prov_3        ind_b           30  30   30  50   30  60
```

The filter condition is `(df[('country2', '2017', 2)] <= 30) & (df[('country2', '2018', 2)] <= 30)` and the filtered data is:

```py
dffiltered = df[(df[('country2', '2017', 2)] <= 30) & (df[('country2', '2018', 2)] <= 30)]

#                         country2
# year                        2017     2018     2019
# country1                       1   2    2   4    3   6
# data_provider indicator
# prov_1        ind_a            4  30    5  30   30  30
# prov_2        ind_a           30  30   30  30    6  30
# prov_3        ind_b           30  30   30  50   30  60
```

I would like to sort the values by the columns where the 2nd level is equal to '2'. For example:

```py
dfsorted = dffiltered.sort_values([('country2', '2017', 2), ('country2', '2018', 2)], ascending=[False, False])
```

But is there any other way that I only have to give the value `2`, instead of `[('country2', '2017', 2), ('country2', '2018', 2)]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pd.MultiIndex.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html) to retrieve the values for level 2 of your MultiIndex and then use boolean indexing on `dffiltered.columns` to filter out the needed columns. Since [`df.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) expects a "Name or list of names to sort by" for the `by` parameter, you will need to add [`pd.MultiIndex.tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.tolist.html).

```
dfsorted = dffiltered.sort_values(dffiltered
                                  .columns[dffiltered.columns.get_level_values(2)==2]
                                  .tolist(), 
                                  ascending=[False, False])

dfsorted

                        country2                      
year                        2017     2018     2019    
country1                       1   2    2   4    3   6
data_provider indicator                               
prov_2        ind_a           30  30   30  30    6  30
prov_3        ind_b           30  30   30  50   30  60
prov_1        ind_a            4  30    5  30   30  30
```

Given the fact that your filter is on the same columns, you can also refactor this a bit:

```
cols = df.columns[df.columns.get_level_values(2)==2].tolist()
dfsorted2 = df[df[cols].le(30).all(axis=1)].sort_values(cols, ascending=[False,False])

dfsorted2.equals(dfsorted)
# True, i.e. same result as above
```